# what advatanges does it have using a Angular Material table over a native html table?

Tags: angular, html-table, angular-material

Asking more because I find more confusing and complicating creating a table with angular material:

```
    <table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" matSort class="mat-elevation-z8 property-list" multiTemplateDataRows>

<!-- 
      <ng-container [matColumnDef]="column" *ngFor="let column of propertyColumns">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>{{ propertyColumnLabels[column] }}</th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">
          <div class="col-{{ column }} prop-cell">{{ row[column] }}</div>
        </td>
      </ng-container> -->

      <ng-container [matColumnDef]="'id'">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>ID</th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">
          <div class="col-id prop-cell">{{ row.id }}</div>
        </td>
      </ng-container>

      <ng-container [matColumnDef]="'category'">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>{{ 'Category' | _: trans.lang }}</th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">
          <div class="col-category prop-cell">{{ categoryLabels[row.category] | _: trans.lang }}</div>
        </td>
      </ng-container>
      
      <ng-container [matColumnDef]="'contract_type'">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>{{ 'Contract' | _: trans.lang }}</th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">
          <div class="col-contract_type prop-cell">{{ contractLabels[row.contract_type] | _: trans.lang }}</div>
        </td>
      </ng-container>
...
```

```
    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>ID</th>
          <th>{{ 'Category' | _: trans.lang }}</th>
          <th>{{ 'Contract' | _: trans.lang }}</th>
          <th>{{ 'Price' | _: trans.lang }}</th>
          <th>{{ 'City' | _: trans.lang }}</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr *ngFor="let row of dataSource">
          <td>x</td>
          <td>x</td>
          <td>x</td>
          <td>x</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
```

I am looking for good reasons to get rid of them, since I find hard to style and maintain.

Comment: as far as I'm concerned, it's just a matter of time. If in the project you have a real pro in angular material and you like the rendering, then go.
Otherwise, I find no interest in it.

Comment: Angular Material Table just provides the API to generate the table with Material UI theme. And also provides sorting, pagination etc. It’s up to you whether to use it or not. If you go with simple table approach, you have to write the pagination/sorting logic and add styles for better visual appearance. In cases where you’re using lots of tables, you can have an abstraction aka make a generic data-table to support your needs.

Comment: both are valid reasons, I am still undecided between both. I would leverage the mat-table only if that would provide different visualization (ex list style vs table style)